# The same 100% width of element when content shifts from overflow scroll and overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

This is a bit complicated...

[live demo](http://deerdana.iamloganmyers.com/shop)

Simple explanation:
There is a main section of content with 2 columns with images that is width:100%; overflow scrolls by default. but if you click on any of those images it brings up a slide over that covers 50% of the screen that sits on top of the main section of content it also freezes the main content in place by making overflow:hidden; with javascript.

The issue is that the images in the main section of content shift slightly because the scrollbar is being removed and added again (but to the slide over, so that the slide over can scroll and the main section will stay fixed)

Is there anyway to fix this issue and still keep the main section of content with a width of 100%? I have already attempted to make it so that the main section is content is a calculated width of 100%-size of scroll bar but this method still makes it slightly resize the images (this is already implemented in the live demo).

I should also note that I do not want 2 scrollbars...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Any code/markup/demo related to your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to follow some random link to help you. Instead, put the [**minimum** complete example](/help/mcve) in the question (perhaps using Stack Snippets, the `<>` button in the toolbar).

Comment: sorry!thanks will do

Answer (score 0):

Set the `#wrapper` to `width:100vw;` and the `body` to `overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:hidden;`.